# Laravel Import CSV files of Parent and Child records in one Go

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am stuck here while importing orders and order_item records to the database using Laravel. Below is my database schema.

Orders table
id, order_no, company_id, service_type

order_item table
id, order_id, item_name, item_location, item_sku, item_quantity,item_amount,item_cube,item_length

The scenario is that I have multiple items against single order, I am stuck in getting an idea of how to make it functional.

My CSV file import will be like below
[image]

Below is my simple code, I want to make it functional for orders with multiple order items.

```
 public function importOrder(Request $request)
 {
        $file = $request->file('po_file');
        //dd($file);
        $fileName='order_list_'.$request->get('company_id').'_'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'.csv';
        if ($file->isValid()) {
            $file->move('order_list', $fileName);
        }

       $handle = fopen("order_list/".$fileName, "r");

       if ($handle !== FALSE){
            $column_name=fgetcsv($handle,1000,',');
            //dd($column_name);
            if($column_name[0] == 'order_no' && $column_name[1] == 'company_id' && $column_name[2] == 'service_type' && $column_name[3] == 'item_name' && $column_name[4] == 'item_location' && $column_name[5] == 'item_sku' && $column_name[6] == 'item_quantity' && $column_name[7] == 'item_amount' && $column_name[8] == 'item_cube' && $column_name[9] == 'item_length' ) {
                    //nothing
            }else{
                //echo "error";
                //exit;
                return Response::json(['msg' => 'File Format is In-Valid']);
            }
        }
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
        {
            $customer_email=$data[4];

              //insert order in orders table  
              $query_status_id=  DB::table('orders')->insertGetId(
                    [
                        'order_no' => $data[0],
                        'company_id' => $data[1],
                        'service_type' => $data[2],
                    ]
                );
                if($query_status_id>0){
                  $query_status=TRUE;
                  //insert multiple order items in order_item table
                  $items = DB::table('order_item')->insert([
                    'order_id'      => $query_status_id,
                    'item_name'     => $data[3],    
                    'item_location' => $data[4],
                    'item_sku'      => $data[5],    
                    'item_quantity' => $data[6],
                    'item_amount'   =>  $data[7],
                    'item_cube'     =>  $data[8],
                    'item_length'   => $data[9],
                  ]
                  );
                }


        } 
        fclose($handle);
        return Response::json(['msg' => 'Orders imported']);;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by making some changes in CSV import file.

[image]

Through this way, I can easily import multiple items against single order and customer. Below is my code where I am looking for a same order number, and if found in the database, I am inserting its id along with order items records and if not, I will first insert the order, get the last inserted id, and insert it into the database.

Below is a script part, where I am handling the import of multiple items against a single order.

```
             if($customer_id > 0){
              //insert order in orders table  
              $order_detail = Orders::where('order_no', $data[8])->first();
              if(empty($order_detail->id)){
                $query_status_id=  DB::table('orders')->insertGetId(
                  [
                      'order_no' => $data[8],
                      'company_id' => $data[9],
                      'customer_id' => $customer_id,
                      'service_type' => $data[10],
                  ]
                );
              }else {
                $query_status_id = $order_detail->id;
              }
              
            if($query_status_id>0){
              $items = DB::table('order_item')->insert([
                'order_id'      => $query_status_id,
                'item_name'     => $data[11],   
                'location' => $data[12],
                'item_sku'      => $data[13],   
                'item_quantity' => $data[14],
                'item_amount'   =>  $data[15],
                'item_cube'     =>  $data[16],
                'item_length'   => $data[17],
              ]);
            }

            }
```

Hope this will help others in the future.